# how to add data to a dynamically added div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to prepend data to my dynamically added div - here is my code -

`<script type="text/javascript">`

`var addedDiv=0;`
`$(document).on("submit",".postFromAdd",function(event){`
         `event.preventDefault();`
         `var tmp = "#addedDiv"+addedDiv;`
         `$("#showPostedData").prepend("<div id="+ tmp +"></div>");` 
         `// tmp having the id of my dymanically added div ,` 
         `//now I want to add some data to this div`
         `//i did like --`
         `$(tmp).prepend("<p>Dynamic data here</p>");`
         `addedDiv++;`
`});`
`</script>`

but `$(tmp).prepend("<p>Dynamic data here</p>");` not working . how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

remove id selector # from variable.

```
var tmp = "addedDiv"+addedDiv;
$('#'+tmp).prepend("<p>Dynamic data here</p>");
```

Comment: I've aready added # in this line -- var tmp = "#addedDiv"+addedDiv;

Comment: you dont need to add selector in variable that way it should be `var tmp = "addedDiv"+addedDiv;`

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors are the problem, since the `tmp` is assigned as the id don't prefix it with `#` add the id selector when you use it as an selector.

```
var addedDiv = 0;
$(document).on("submit", ".postFromAdd", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //no # here
    var tmp = "addedDiv" + addedDiv;
    $("#showPostedData").prepend("<div id=" + tmp + "></div>");
    //add # here
    $('#' + tmp).prepend("<p>Dynamic data here</p>");
    addedDiv++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var addedDiv=0;
$(document).on("submit",".postFromAdd",function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         var $div=$('<div/>',{'id':'#addedDiv'+addedDiv});
         $div.prepend("<p>Dynamic data here</p>");
         $("#showPostedData").prepend($div);         
         addedDiv++;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
               $('#'+tmp).html('<p>you can ad text or html here</p>');
```